# Missing Header files in newer kernel

Tags: kernel, linux-headers

I am trying to install a source package on a fresh install of 20.04 running kernel 5.13.0-28-generic.  The package requires <config/modversions.h>.  This package installed with no problems on 5.8.0-59-generic.  I have linux-headers-5.13.0-28-generic installed, but /usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-28-generic/include/config only contains the names of header files in all caps without the .h, i.e. MODVERSIONS.  These are all empty files.  I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the header package.  Have these files been depreciated, or is there something wrong with this version?